# setPrimitiveValue for Transient property not saved

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am using some Transient property on my NSManagedObject to pre-calculate things that only need to be calculated once when dependent property is updated but when I reset the value on Transient property it never gets to saved.

For example:

```
-(NSString*)age {
    // notify core data to access value
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"age"];
    // get primitive value
    NSString* age = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"age"];
    // is age already exist?
    if ( age == nil ) {
        // get age
        age = [GlobalHelper convertToAgeStringWithUTCDateOfBirth:(NSString*)self.dateOfBirth];
        // set primitive value
        [self setPrimitiveValue:age forKey:@"age"];
    }
    // notify core data done access value
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"age"];
    return age;
}

-(void)setDateOfBirth:(id)dateOfBirth {
        // change value for key
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"age"];
        // set primitive
        [self setPrimitiveValue:dateOfBirth forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:nil forKey:@"age"];
        // did change value for key
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"age"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
}
```

So as you can see from above code, when I am sync this object and when "dateOfBirth" field is updated it try to set "age" to "nil" and when accessing "age" field and if it is "nil" then calculate the age and never calculate it again.

However the problem is when I am setting "age" field to "nil" in "setDateOfBirth" setting it never saved and when I am accessing age again "age" property still has the previous value but "dateOfBirth" is updated.

Any help remotely related to this topic would be very much appreciated, I am having big trouble about this...

EDIT: The logic I got above works perfect in scenario where both setter and getter calls from same context (same thread context), problem only occurs when setter called from completion block of AFNetworking api with private queue and getter called from main thread after merged.

It seems that when I am saving from the context where AFNetworking completion block it only saves the dateOfBirth but not age value which it sets to nil so after merge and when getter calls from the main thread "age" has previous value so it never get to calculated again.

Comment: You just said age is a transient property, why would you expect it to be saved?

Comment: transient property is not saved into storage but it saves to memory context and the purpose of transient property is well explained in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Comment: You need to post the part of your code where you are saving these records. It could an issue of managed object contexts crossing threads, or merging changes with transient properties (see details closer to the bottom of this page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html)

Comment: Hi Rog, thank you very much for the reference url which exactly explain what my problem is in "Merging changes with transient properties" section, and now I understand why my transient property has previous value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set the age when reading the age. That seems very odd design and also fails to call the appropriate key-value coding notifications.

Instead follow your original logic: if date of birth changes, update age. You should do this in `setDateOfBirth` and call the appropriate key-value coding notifications in the setter for `age`.

```
-(void) setDateOfBirth:(id)newValue {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:newValue forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"];

    self.age = [GlobalHelper 
       convertToAgeStringWithUTCDateOfBirth:(NSString*)newValue];
}

-(void)age {
  [self willAccessValueForKey:@"age"];
  NSString* age = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"age"];
  [self didAccessValueForKey:@"age"];
  if (age == nil) {
      age = [GlobalHelper 
         convertToAgeStringWithUTCDateOfBirth:(NSString*)self.dateOfBirth];
  }
  self.age = age;
  return age;
}
```

However, with all that you have to ask yourself how expensive the `convertAge` call really is. In all but the most extreme cases, one simple getter that makes the conversion is actually all you need.

Also, I think your `dateOfBirth` property should have a standard managed object property type, not `id`. Is it a string? Then you should declare it as `NSString`, not use `id` and cast.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer and the reason dateOfBirth property is id because it is Transformer type which encoded for security reason but that's not related to this..  the reason I did reset the age when dateOfBirth property is set and calculate it from age getter only if age is null so I  can make sure it only calculated once.  and it is not expensive for one converting API call but imagine if you have hundreds or thousands of  field you need to display in table view and it get to call convert api every time it scrolls..

Comment: The logic I got works perfect in scenario where both setter and getter calls from same context (same thread context), problem only occurs when setter called from completion block of AFNetworking api with private queue and getter called from main thread after merged.

Comment: If you just use a getter, even in a tableview with 1000s of entries it will only be called for the rows on screen, so no problem. - As for the thread problem, you should pass the changes up to your main thread (e.g. by saving the parent context) and then save.

Comment: That's not entirely true, if you have 100 cell in your table view and each cell display age string then when you scroll from first cell to bottom cell. it refresh each cell right? and calling the convert API and it will kill the performance of the scrolling. so either you do it in queue or pre-refresh way to prevent multiple API calls for same value. and "dateOfBirth" is UTC date time standard string looks something like this "1933-04-21T00:00:00+09:30" it need to be converted into NSDate using NSDateFormatter and it is not the fastest API in Cocoa..

Comment: And thread problem, the reason I am using queue is not to disturb the performance on main thread.. so I sync all the entities in background private queue and merge it later.